# SOAPConnectionFactory.newInstance() returns null in JAX-RS resource

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, soap, jaxp

I have a JAX-RS resource, using Jersey, that provides a resource `InstallOrder`. When there is a POST Request for this resource it shall make a SOAP request and send it to yet another web service. I'm using the `jakarta.xml.soap-api 1.4.2` library for the creation and sending of the `SOAPMessage`.

Before creating the `SOAPMessage` I'm getting a `NullPointerException` because `SOAPConnectionFactory.newInstance()` returns `null`. The code snippet looks like this:

```
SOAPConnectionFactory scf = SOAPConnectionFactory.newInstance()
SOAPConnection connection = scf.createConnection();
```

The `scf` is unexpectedly `null` here. I'm using the exact same code in another SOAP web service with the same library and it works like a charm. I don't get where the problem is.

Comment: When you say you are using *"the exact same code in another SOAP web service with the same library and it works like a charm"*, what does that mean? Is it a different environment? Is it the same? Are there differences, like maybe a different version of the library, different versions of Java, different system environment?

Comment: It is the same Tomcat in openshift environment / image. Therefore same java, same env, same version declared in POM ... I think I will bypass this problem by not using the SOAP libraries but simply send a http post which holds the SOAP body declared as text/xml. At least through Postman that works. Therefore it should work when send from a WebService too, right?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and in my case I solved it by explicitly adding this to my POM file.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.xml.messaging.saaj</groupId>
    <artifactId>saaj-impl</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.1</version>
</dependency>
```

If you're not using Maven then this won't help directly, however it might help to know that behind the scenes the SOAPConnectionFactory uses com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.client.p2p.HttpSOAPConnectionFactory to implement SOAP. At least this is true for javax.xml.soap-api 1.4.0.